# Sorted generic sequence

Tags: scala, generics

I am new in scala. I have a generic class,

```
object Main extends App{
  val strings = new CustomSeq("b", "c", "a")
  val numbers = new CustomSeq(1,5,4,2)
}


class CustomSeq[T](initialElems: T*) {

   private val elems = scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[T]()

   elems ++= initialElems
}
```

And I want, to keep the list inside class sorted. So for example in this case I want to get in strings and numbers
List(a,b,c) and List(1,2,4,5).
How can I do it?

Comment: There's going to be a name clash with your `Seq` and the one in the standard library, by the way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make constructor private and define factory method creating instance with sorted `initialElems`

```
class Seq[T] private(initialElems: T*) {
  override def toString: String = initialElems.toString
}

object Seq {
  def apply[T: Ordering](initialElems: T*): Seq[T] = new Seq(initialElems.sorted:_*)
}

val strings = Seq("b", "c", "a")
val numbers = Seq(1,5,4,2)
println(strings) // ArraySeq(a, b, c)
println(numbers) // ArraySeq(1, 2, 4, 5)
```

Surely you'll have to watch that after your operations in `Seq` (if you add any) `initialElems` remains sorted.